# Datepicker creating a six months calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am triying to do a page with a Calendar. The idea is to put in the page the six first months in the year and with a button, show the other six months.

[image]

I tried with datapicker, searching in the web and using different methods, but I dont achieve that.

Someone knows hot to put, at less, the six months separately?

Comment: the datepicker object accepts `numberOfMonths` as a parameter, which accepts an array of the months, or a single digit representing how many months you want to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `defaultDate` to the beginning of the current year. Combined with the `numberOfMonths` and `stepMonths` methods, we should be able to achieve something similar to what you're looking for.

JS:

```
// Get the first day of the year (ie. Jan 1, 2013)
var firstOfTheYear = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);

// Set your datepicker options
$(".calendar").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [2, 3],
    stepMonths: 6,
    defaultDate: firstOfTheYear
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RyanWalters/VYvLb/